# Transparent lines on 3D plot

Tags: plot, 3d, plotly

Does anyone know how to make a 3D line plot where the lines are semi-transparent using Plotly or a different tool?

The 3D plot I am trying to create is here: https://plot.ly/~starhammer/238/

A 2D example of the transparency is here: https://plot.ly/~starhammer/274

This was achieved by adjusting the opacity parameter of the line in Plotly. I have tried changing the line opacity in the 3D plot but it doesn't seem to do anything,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

If yes, you can adjust your opacity by setting your own 'rgba' color ('a' stands for Alpha and defines the opacity).

From your workspace go to

- *TRACES* => *Style*
- under the *Line* section, click on the color button and set your desired 'rgba' color

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but I just seem to get a "lighter" colour rather than increased trasparency. Here is the plot with trace line colour rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2) [link]https://plot.ly/~starhammer/300 and here is the same plot with trace line colour rgb(204, 204, 204) [link]https://plot.ly/~starhammer/302. To me they look the same.

Comment: I can't see your plots.  could you save them publicly?  Meanwhile, here is an example for 2-D plot with transparent lines using 'rgba': https://plot.ly/~neda/5521

Comment: I have now made them public, I understand your 2D example but I can't get this to extend to 3D. When modifying the alpha in 3D it just seems to change the colour and keeps it 100% opaque rather than more transparent (see examples above), i.e. lines behind other lines are not visible at all when they overlap. Sorry if I am not explaining this very well, I have made another plot to try and illustrate this, it is a 2D plot (constant Z) in the 3D space with variable alpha, there is only ever "solid colours", even on the overlaps [https://plot.ly/~starhammer/317](https://plot.ly/~starhammer/317)

Comment: @Mac89 Oh thanks for clarifying, it seems that you have discovered a bug!  Our team is working on it and it should be fixed soon!  I will keep you updated

Comment: I can confirm that this feature has now been fixed